# Account Extended Public Key from mnemonic

Tags: python, php

tell me please, how we can receive Account Extended Public Key from mnemonic phrase via PHP or Python? Or possible in internet we have ready console scripts?

I'm going to https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ converter, and put mnemonic phrase

fetch detect laugh camp coil salute any guide scheme monster alone slot

in field BIP 39 Mnemonic. After I selected BIP84 in Derivation Path.

After this in field Account Extended Public Key we received correct Account Extended Public Key:

zpub6sApCAVpVCnUJQbmPfjepgCtNW1781fiD2ChuPdEs2oWEDpgKh5QJdcSJJL29Q5XwiJ2WvWo71eteRubzDmGH1SYMhg2cL7Um8uYbnVGk6A

Thanks.
I will thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools) python library

```
>>> from cryptotools import Xprv
>>> xprv = Xprv.from_mnemonic('fetch detect laugh camp coil salute any guide scheme monster alone slot', addresstype='P2WPKH')

>>> zpub = (xprv/84./0./0.).to_xpub()
>>> zpub.encode()
'zpub6sApCAVpVCnUJQbmPfjepgCtNW1781fiD2ChuPdEs2oWEDpgKh5QJdcSJJL29Q5XwiJ2WvWo71eteRubzDmGH1SYMhg2cL7Um8uYbnVGk6A'
```